# R: sorting indiviual letters from separate columns and merge them in one string

Tags: r, string, sorting, concatenation

I need a simple R function to sort, in alphabetical order, letters from col1:col3, by row, and concatenate them into one string, *i.e.* `"a" "c" "b"` and `"c" "a" "b"` will give the same string `"abc"`, which will be stored in a new column. My input data.frame looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 val
a c b 3
e a a 2
c c b 1
c a b 6
...
```

The result:

```
col1 col2 col3 val col4
a c b 3 abc
e a a 2 aae
c c b 1 bcc
c a b 6 abc
...
```

Afterward, I need to sum up the rows yielding the same string, in order to obtain a new data.frame looking as below:

```
col1 val
abc 9
aae 5
bbc 12
...
```

Comment: 1. Use something like `d$res <- apply(d,1,paste,collapse='')`; 2. Check out `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages, e.g. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Don't use `apply` with margin of 1 for just pasting. It's awfully inefficient. You could do `do.call(paste, c(sep = "", df[-4]))` instead. Though you are still left with internal sorting.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I see for once a justified use of `apply` for a `data.frame`, since the sorting is needed. I agree that usually is inefficient, but in this case may make sense (at least until someone gives a more efficient way).

Comment: @nicola if you performing the sort too, then it could be justified. I was mainly disagreeing with the comment above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Many times I thought that R needs a "character sorting" function, which I don't think it exists. I wonder why (should be pretty easy to implement at the C level).

Comment: @nicola I was just looking into `stringi` for such thing. Maybe worth a FR

Comment: `vapply(xxx,function(x) rawToChar(as.raw(sort(as.integer(charToRaw(x))))),"")` could do the character sorting, but I guess is _very_ inefficient (and don't consider locale of course).

Comment: @nicola I also saw this somewhere `sapply(lapply(strsplit(s, NULL), sort), paste, collapse = "")` but indeed it seems like a C level implementation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df$col4<-apply(df[,1:3],1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse=""))
#  col1 col2 col3 val col4
#1    a    c    b   3  abc
#2    e    a    a   2  aae
#3    c    c    b   1  bcc
#4    c    a    b   6  abc
```

Then you use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(val ~ col4,df,sum)
#  col4 val
#1  aae   2
#2  abc   9
#3  bcc   1
```